# receiving data from parent component vue.js: prop being mutated,

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an error in the console that is saying:

> Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.
>   Prop being mutated: "sortType"

My root file contains an api and a filter function. I am sending that data to components. Everything was fine 'til I added some sorting in filterList().

This is how I am receiving the `sortType`:

```
<div id="toprow">
       // slider codes...
        <select id="sortBox" v-model="sortData" v-on:change="filterList">
            <option value="">sorting</option>
            <option value="price">cheapest</option>
            <option value="created_at">newest</option>
        </select>
</div>


props:["filterList", "slider", "sliderX", "sortType"],
components: {
    vueSlider,
},
data() {
    return {
        sortData: this.sortType
    }
},
methods: {
    filterList(newType){
        this.$emit('update:type', newType)
    }
}
```

Below, my root file...

```
<app-toprow v-on:update:type="sortType = $event" :filterList="filterList" :slider="slider" :sliderX="sliderX" :sortType="sortType"></app-toprow>


data(){
    return {
        api: [],
        sortType:"",
    }
},
mounted(){
    axios.get("ajax").then(response => {
        this.api = response.data
    })
},
methods: {

},
computed: {
    filterList: function () {
        let filteredStates = this.api.filter((estate) => {
            return (this.keyword.length === 0 || estate.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
            (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(estate.rooms)) &&
            (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(estate.region))});

            if(this.sortType == 'price') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => prev.price - curr.price);
            }
            if(this.sortType == 'created_at') {
                filteredStates = filteredStates.sort((prev, curr) => Date.parse(curr.created_at) - Date.parse(prev.created_at));
            }

            return filteredStates;
    },
}
}
```

Okay, am I doing something wrong when I receiving the sortType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the select option didn't has default value (the value is always `sorting` on page load)?  if yes you don't have to use  v-model

if it has default value, try use `:value` instead of `v-model`, and use the props `sortType` as the value.

also you can't use same name on `filterList`, try using different variable for the function.

```
<div id="toprow">
       // slider codes...
        <select id="sortBox" :value="sortType" v-on:change="change">
            <option value="">sorting</option>
            <option value="price">cheapest</option>
            <option value="created_at">newest</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

on the change Function

```
export default {
    methods: {
        change(e){
            this.$emit('update:type', e.target.value)
        }
    }
}
```

on your parent component

```
<app-toprow v-on:update:type="sortType = $event" :filterList="filterList" :slider="slider" :sliderX="sliderX" :sortType="sortType"></app-toprow>
```

Comment: and this is the best answer. thank you so much. it's working like a magic now. the thing I don't understand. How `change()` knows data and interreact with  `filterList()` because my filter code inside filterList() in parent. but change() function knows that and interreact with it. Although I did't mention `filterList()` in `select`  like before...

Comment: you are welcome!  . when you change the select option, it will trigger `change` method, the `change` method then pass / emit the value to the parent. it modify the `sortType` variable. And since `sortType` variable is used in the `filterList`, and `filterList` is a computed property, the computed property will triggered when any variable used in that property is changed

Answer (score 1):

You pass `sortType` as a prop into the child component and simultaneously mutate it using the `v-model` in select, thus receiving this error.

Your child component should be something like:

```
<div id="toprow">
// slider codes...
    <select id="sortBox" v-model="selectedSort" v-on:change="filterList">
        <option value="">sorting</option>
        <option value="price">cheapest</option>
        <option value="created_at">newest</option>
     </select>
</div>


export default {
    data() => ({
        selectedSort: this.sortType
    })
    props:["filterList", "slider", "sliderX", "sortType"],
    components: {
        vueSlider,
    },
    methods: {
        filterList(newType){
            this.$emit('update:type', newType)
        }
    }
}
```

Now on the `v-on:change=filterList` you should emit a custom event on the parent that notifies him that the sorting has changed.

And something like this on the parent:

```
<app-toprow v-on:update:type="sortType = $event" :filterList="filterList" :slider="slider" :sliderX="sliderX" :sortType="sortType"></app-toprow>
```

Relevant SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722100/7482509
Relevant docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: thank you for answering. the only thing I didn't understand here. this part. `filterList(newType){
    this.$emit('update:type', newType)
}` where should I insert this inside my filterList() ?

Comment: why don't u put that snippet into `export default { ... }` just below `components:`?

Comment: you mean in child component make a `computed: {` and use that snippet inside? But I already using filterList()  and receving that filterList() from parent. just check the question... So... it doesn't make sense...  @AliD.

Comment: i updated my answer. The filterList should go into the child component's methods.

Comment: thank you for update. But I already tried that. you see in the question `filterList()` is the function in the parent and I am receiving that too... that's why when I recreate in child. of course I get error. I need `filterList()` in the parent that how I do sorting/filtering... That's why I am having this error: `Method "filterList" has already been defined as a prop.` By the way updated the question with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

**FIX FOR CLONED[i].apply**

[Vue 2 - Uncaught TypeError: cloned[i].apply is not a function at HTMLInputElement.invoker (vue.esm.js?65d7:1810) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349800/vue-2-uncaught-typeerror-clonedi-apply-is-not-a-function-at-htmlinputelemen)

basically you should just change the prop name `filterList` to something else

**NEW ANSWER**

here's an update answer, prop `filterList` is the same name as in method I do think that is conflict. also i do think that you don't need to send `filterList` method from parent to children because you are already listening on if via `update:type`

```
methods: {
    filterList(event){
        // use the v-model reactive feature..
        this.$emit('update:type', this.sortData)
        // if you don't like this.sortData -> uncomment below
        // this.$emit('update:type', event.target.value)
    }
}
```

**OLD**

why don't you use `mounted()` for initializing `sortData: this.sortType`...

```
data() {
    return {
        sortData: null
    }
},
mounted() {
  this.sortData = this.sortType
}
```

P.S.

Just my theory...
I could not explain clearly why this is happening but I do think that this is because vue is reactive and all data values should not have a value directly from prop. because if you think about it if it came from prop **DIRECTLY** therefor editing it should also edit the prop..

but I don't really know why it's doing that, better ask that another time.

Comment: I also tried that in the mounted hook like this   `this.sortData = this.sortType` but having this error.  `cloned[i].apply is not a function` by the way assuming `:` is a syntax error in your mounted code

Comment: Sorry about the syntax-error... but where are you calling ```cloned[i].apply``` ?

Comment: I do need to send `filterList()` because inside that `filterList()` not just `sortType` also has other filters I want all filters connected. That's why sending it... for example my slider filter works fine... But my sortType is not running...

Comment: and by the way. that  `filterList()` has include sortType filter too.. if you look closely...

Comment: i would like to suggest to install vue-devtools (browser extension) for better Debugging.. ;)